# Invoke server with PowerShell to run python script: can't open file [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, powershell, argparse, errno

I understand this is a permission's issue but I can't tell where.

Basically I have a PowerShell script that gets some info from a user locally, then sends it to an API via python. The API I am posting to for some reason can't take JSON from PowerShell properly (thinks it's malformed no matter what you do) so I am using python to do the last bit.

**The call has to come from our server ip** so I have to pass the info to the server & python file and invoke the server to call the API. I do so with:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {python.exe "PATH TO .PY" -id $using:CaseID -tag $using:serviceTag -m $using:message}
```

I get:

```
C:\PATH-TO\python.exe: can't open file 'PATH TO .PY': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The python file is on a network share. I've tried giving the "everyone" group read/write to the folder to see the outcome but it is still the same.

My only thought comes down to what user is the scriptblock running under when the server executes, and if I need to provide credentials.

Comment: Try adding `-Authentication Credssp` to Invoke-Command call (you have to have CredSSP enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp?view=powershell-7). The issue seems to be in that your credential is not passed to the network location.

Comment: This is the Kerberos double-hop problem; you can authenticate to the first server for the PS remoting session, but from there your remote server connection is not allowed to use your logon token to talk to the next server where the file share is. "Everyone" permission does not cover unauthenticated users, I think you would need [Anonymous Logon account for that](http://nikolar.com/2015/03/10/creating-network-share-with-anonymous-access/) which is a bad solution. Multiple [alternative solutions and workarounds exist](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=powershell+double+hop&ia=web).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments stated, it was infamous PowerShell double hop issue.

**Server A** (me) invoking **Server B** to run the script on "Server C" (The network share).

The reason I say "Server C" is because the network share was attached to **Server B** itself. I used the direct path instead of the network share path in the script block and everything worked. Basically Server A to B at that point.

Before, I was going to go the route of passing credentials (not a fan of Credssp), but even this did not work when I passed them.

Best doc for this was here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely